# How to save Webview state when switching between different Fragments in a Tablayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am making a very simple webview app that places different subpages of a website under different tabs (using tablayout), i.e. messages, orders etc. The individual webviews are created using fragments. The idea is that the user can quickly switch back and forth between pages. While testing, when I switch to the tab directly next to the one I'm on and then back, the page is exactly how it was when I left the tab. However, I switch to a tab that is further than one tab away from the one I'm currently on, and then switch back to the previous tab, the page is reloaded. I want the page state to be remembered when the user switches to any other tab. How can this be done?

TL;DR: how to retain webview states when switching between tabs using tablayout with fragments that each display a different webview?

For reference, the code of one of the fragments:

```
class BrowseFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse, container, false)

    val webViewBrowse = myView.findViewById(R.id.webViewBrowse) as WebView;
    webViewBrowse.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    webViewBrowse.loadUrl("https://websitehome.page")
    webViewBrowse.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

    return myView
}
```

}

Controlled by a SectionsPagerAdapter.tk:

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(private val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

    return when (position) {
        0 -> {
            BrowseFragment()
        }
        1 -> {
            SecondFragment()
        }
        2 -> {
            ThirdFragment()
        }
        3 -> {
            FourthFragment()
        }
        else -> BrowseFragment()
    }

}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return context.resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    // Show 4 total pages.
    return 4
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Pager Adapter Deprecated

**Use ViewPager2**

First set offscreenPageLimit to your viewPager2

```
//YOUR_ID
  yourViewPager2.offscreenPageLimit =3
```

**Use PagerStateAdapter**

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(mActivity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(mActivity) {

private var mBrowseFragment: BrowseFragment? = null
private var mSecondFragment: SecondFragment? = null
private var mThirdFragment: ThirdFragment? = null
private var mFourthFragment: FourthFragment? = null

override fun getItemCount() = 4

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
  return when (position) {
        0 -> {
            if (mBrowseFragment != null) {
                mBrowseFragment!!
            } else {
                mBrowseFragment = BrowseFragment()
                mBrowseFragment!!
            }
        }
        1 -> {
            if (mSecondFragment != null) {
                mSecondFragment!!
            } else {
                mSecondFragment = SecondFragment()
                mSecondFragment!!
            }
        }
        2 -> {
            if (mThirdFragment != null) {
                mThirdFragment!!
            } else {
                mThirdFragment = ThirdFragment()
                mThirdFragment!!
            }
        }
        3 -> {
            if (mFourthFragment != null) {
                mFourthFragment!!
            } else {
                mFourthFragment = FourthFragment()
                mFourthFragment!!
            }
        }
        else -> {
            // Else part won't call no need to consider NULL
            mBrowseFragment!!
        }
    }
}
}
```

FragmentStateAdapter have multiple constructor options. I used activity in this sample.

```
FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity)

FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment)

FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager,
        @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle)
```